# Codeception doesn't override parameter in Gitlab

Tags: gitlab, codeception

I have this issue

*********** codeception.yml ***************

```
paths:
    tests: tests

    output: tests/_output
    data: tests/_data
    support: tests/_support
    envs: tests/_envs

actor_suffix: Tester

#amount customer per product

amountPerProduct: 1

wishCountry: 1

wishProduct: 0
```

I am using the param like this:

```
$countryIndex = Configuration::config()['wishCountry'];
```

but on the console I calling the test like this:

```
codecept run tests/acceptance/ChangeCest.php --env chrome --xml --html -o "wishProduct:55"
```

I get this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kfvgf.png)

**QUESTION**: how can I override this config in Gitlab?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this solves your problem but for Codeception v5 (also my current local version v4.2.1) the option is exploded with `:` , i.e. with an appended space. I notice in your screenshot the exception does show the key/value without the space in between, but you didn't specify which version of Codeception you're using.

From `Config.php`:

```php
foreach ($configOptions as $option) {
    $keys = explode(': ', $option);
    //                ^ notice the space here
    if (count($keys) < 2) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('--override should have config passed as "key: value"');
    }
```

https://github.com/Codeception/Codeception/blob/5.0/src/Codeception/Command/Shared/ConfigTrait.php

Comment: I am using V4.1.21

Comment: @ctine My answer is still valid for v4.1, have you tried running with the added space in between key and value? i.e. `-o "wishProduct: 55"`

Answer (score 0):

i find the answer to my problem.
I store the parameters in a new file params.yml

**params.yml**

```
parameters:
    WISH_PRODUCT: 55
```

**codeception.yml**

```
params:
    - params.yml
```

**acceptance.suite.yml**

```
config:
    custom_params:
        wishProduct: %WISH_PRODUCT%
```

**AcceptanceTester.php**

so in AcceptanceTester I can read the values like this

$custom_params = Configuration::suiteSettings('acceptance', Configuration::config())['modules']['custom_params'];